# How to set the value of a slider without triggering the ValueChanged event again in C# in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, slider

I need to update a slider control because I'm implementing the values in steps of 5. But, when I set the value in the Value changed event, the event is triggered again. How can I set the value of a slider within the ValueChanged event without triggering it again?

```
                    partial void sliTip_ValueChanged(UISlider sender)
                    {
                        float newStep = (float)Math.Round((sender.Value) / _stepValue);

                        sender.Value = newStep * _stepValue;  // <-------   triggers event again
                        //sender.SetValue(newStep * _stepValue, false);
                        //NSNumber number = newStep * _stepValue;
                        //sender.SetValueForKey(number, new NSString("Value"));

                        this.lblTip.Text = sender.Value.ToString() + "% tip";
                    }
```

In native Objective-c, you can set the value of a UISlider just fine without the event being triggered:

```
                    slider setValue:self.tip;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  But if all you want to do is prevent the infinite recursion from happening, that should be fairly simple

```
partial void sliTip_ValueChanged(UISlider sender)
{
  float newStep = (float)Math.Round((sender.Value) / _stepValue);
  float newValue = newStep * _stepValue;

  if (sender.Value != newValue) {
    sender.Value = newValue;
    this.lblTip.Text = sender.Value.ToString() + "% tip";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a **TouchUpInside** event that is only triggered once the user lets go of the slider. The TouchUpInside event of course is only triggered once when the user lifts the finger away from the touch screen.